# set src property of img dynamically

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

instead of

```
src="~/Images/MyPage/goals.jpg"
```

I would like something like this:

```
src="'~/Images/MyPage/' + '@MyMethod(1)'"
```

where

```
 public static string MyMethod(int someGivenId)
 {
    switch(someGivenId)
    {

      case 1: return "goals.jpg";    
      case 2: return "goals2.jpg";
      case 3: return "goals3.jpg";    
      default:
              return "goals3.jpg";
   }
}
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: You should just be able to call the method in your cshtml (if you have the using at the top of the page or in your web config) - `src="~/Images/MyPage/@MyMethod(1)"`

Comment: I tried, but no picture shown, only the little default pic of missing image. I also tried something like src='@string.Format("~/Images/MyPage/{0}", @MyMethod(1))' but still not working. I think I'm missing something....

Comment: Need more debugging information - eg is this in your code or in your cshtml?  What exactly is not working?  What does your rendered source code look like?

Comment: My fault, it works as you said. I guess I will delete the question? Or you post your comment as an answer and I will accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the relevant using statement at the top of your cshtml file (or in the view web.config), you should just be able to call the method directly:

```
<img src="~/Images/MyPage/@MyMethod(1)">
```